# Examples or use cases to use enzyme mount when unit test react components?

Tags: reactjs, components, mount, enzyme

There used to be a common use case to full render the component with `componentDidMount`/`componentDidUpdate` lifecycles which shallow render doesn't have.

But since enzyme 3+, shallow rendering turned lifecycles on by default, and it simply feels more like real unit test with good isolation between virtual Dom and real Dom. Could anymore share some examples where using mount still shines? (personally don't think HOC necessarily has to be tested by mount)

> Full DOM rendering is ideal for use cases where you have components that may interact with DOM APIs or need to test components that are wrapped in higher order components.